# OpenCart Theme 'MarketShop' slider issue

Tags: php, themes, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using an opencart theme called MarketShop and as part of the theme it comes with a featured slider on the top of the website. It was all functioning correctly this morning, I went to edit the pictures by removing the original module and recreating it with a different banner. Now the module has been created but its not showing up on the website.

What have I done wrong?

I believe the two modules have identical information but I could be incorrect.

I've tried reupoloading all files from the theme and just skipping any that were identical in order to try and find the missing file with no luck.

Any suggestions besides doing a factory reset are much appreciated!

UPDATE:
Doesn't seem like anyone is able to determine the fault... Going to do a fresh install unless someone wants to first login themeselves and see if they can find the problem?

Comment: may be the module is disabled?

Comment: @AbdoAdel unfortunately no, the module is enabled. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module from the admin control panel with no luck! Remember, this was all working perfectly before I deleted one module...

Comment: do you use vqmod extensions?

Comment: Yes @AbdoAdel I was required to install the vqmod extension although im not sure how it works or is related?

Comment: try deleting all files in this directory `<OC_ROOT>/vqmod/vqcache/...`

Comment: Nope no luck there. I think it must have something more to do with the module that I deleted. When I re-added it maybe I missed something?

Comment: Would I be able to find the module settings somewhere in my themes original installation files or something like that and then re-add anything I've missed from the module that is likely to be causing this issue? @AbdoAdel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82368/discussion-between-abdo-adel-and-brad-andrews).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue myself finallly after a LOT of playing around!

Steps I took to fix this issue were as follows..

First I uninstalled the module and reinstalled (It deleted all tests I made + the original demo items).

Then I clicked the install button again and went to edit.
I added one slideshow item and choose my banner that I'd setup earlier via the banners link in the admin panel.

I then went to LAYOUTS which is found next to the banners link or after you click save in modules at the top a hyperlink to layouts is offered.

Upon going to the layouts section and playing around here for even more time I worked out I needed to go into the Homepage file and click edit (NOT THE ONE NAME DEFAULT)!

I tried this numerous times with the DEFAULT page (Note that my store is even set so that the default theme is default which led me to believe that was the right page, which it is not.

So go into homepage and click edit.

Then add one module with the blue plus. Select the module you've just created earlier. Position it where you want it on the page (to get it to work for me I selected "Content Top" and Sort Order I set to 1 (The other two modules had sort orders of 2 and 3)

And that was that, problem solved!

Hopefully this will help anyone else with similar issues.